# How do I prove ~(A & B) therefore ~A V ~B using natural deduction?

Tags: logic

Been trying to prove this one for a while now and can't crack it.

- Assume ¬(A ∧ B)
- Derive ¬A ∨ ¬B

Comment: No idea ? No attempts done ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think i figured out the solution...

[image]

Comment: sorry to be so ignorant, but i'm amazed that something so obvious has a difficult 19 stage proof! cool

Comment: Yes, this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The result desired is one of the De Morgan rules.  One way to show this is to use the law of the excluded middle on *A*. That is, *A* or *¬A* is true.

This involves considering two cases, *A* and *¬A*. In both cases we need to reach the conclusion, *¬A ∨ ¬B*.

The easy case is *¬A*. Use disjunction introduction to derive the desired result: *¬A ∨ ¬B*

The more difficult case is *A*.   Start a subproof by assuming *B*. What we want is *¬B*, so our goal is to derive a contradiction.  However, if we use conjunction introduction we can derive *A ∧ B*. Since we have a premise this contradictions we have the desired contradiction. This allows us to derive *¬B* through negation introduction. From that result and disjunction introduction we can derive the desired result: *¬A ∨ ¬B*

Since we derived the same result for both cases, *A* and *¬A*, we can conclude using the law of the excluded middle that we have the desired result *¬A ∨ ¬B* which completes the proof.

For a proof checker and a supplementary text see the links below. A proof using the above suggestion took 10 lines:

[image]

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/